# Getting Array Value from Checkbox in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to build a list where user can select any checkbox and it can send all select values for the row to the next page.

Here is what I have:

first page:

```
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
<td><a href="#" onClick="select_all('area', '1');">Check All</a> | <a href="#" onClick="select_all('area', '0');">Uncheck All</a></td>
<td>Item Name</td>
<td>Item Description</td>

        </tr>
<?php
 if ($num_rows == 0) {
           return "No Data Found";
}else{
   while ($row = dbFetchAssoc($result)) {
        $item_id = $row['item_id']; 
       $item_name = $row['item_name'];
        $item_desc = $row['item_desc'];
        $item_qty = $row['item_qty'];
        $item_upc = $row['item_upc'];
         $item_price = $row['item_price'];
         $vendor_id = $row['vendor_id'];
 ?>
        <tr>
        <td> <input type="checkbox" name="area[]" value="<?=$item_id?>" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="item_name[]" value="<?=$item_name?>"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="item_desc[]" value="<?=$item_desc?>"></td>
        </tr>
<?php
}
}
?>
        <tr><td colspan="3"><input type="submit"></td></tr>
    </table>
  </form>
```

Next Page:

```
<table>
    <tr><td colspan="3"><?php "Total Item(s) selected: "; echo count($_POST['area']); ?></td></tr>
<?php

if(!empty($_POST['area'])) {
    foreach($_POST['area'] as $check) {
            echo "<tr><td>".$check."</td><td>".$_POST['item_name']."</td><td>".$_POST['item_name']."</td></tr>"; 
    }
}
?>
</table>
```

I need to read the item_name and item_desc value as well. How do I get it?

Answer (score 0):

You need the key:

```
if(!empty($_POST['area'])) {
    foreach($_POST['area'] as $key => $check) {
            echo "<tr><td>".$check."</td><td>".$_POST['item_name'][$key]."</td><td>".$_POST['item_desc'][$key]."</td></tr>"; 
    }
}
```

As Marc said in his answer it would probably be better to set key's in your loop creating the input.

```
<?php
 if ($num_rows == 0) {
           return "No Data Found";
}else{
    $counter = 0;
   while ($row = dbFetchAssoc($result)) {
        $counter++;
        $item_id = $row['item_id']; 
       $item_name = $row['item_name'];
        $item_desc = $row['item_desc'];
        $item_qty = $row['item_qty'];
        $item_upc = $row['item_upc'];
         $item_price = $row['item_price'];
         $vendor_id = $row['vendor_id'];
 ?>
        <tr>
        <td> <input type="checkbox" name="area[<?=$counter?>]" value="<?=$item_id?>" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="item_name[<?=$counter?>]" value="<?=$item_name?>"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="item_desc[<?=$counter?>]" value="<?=$item_desc?>"></td>
        </tr>
<?php
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($_POST['area'] as $key => $check) {
    echo $check . $_POST['item_name'][$key];
}
```

assuming that there's an exact 1:1 correspondence between your three submitted arrays. Remember that checkboxes which are **NOT** checked do **NOT** get submitted with the form, so this is most likely NOT true and this code will not work as written.